# How sum rows and get result permount mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I want SUM my rows in table to SUM per month, example i
have table, like this :

```
no total_a total_b date
1    2        3    2017-06-12
2    1        2    2017-06-13
3    4        8    2017-07-04
```

and i tried to use query like this

```
SELECT    SUM(total_a) as a, SUM(total_b) as b
FROM      table_visit 
WHERE     YEAR(date) = '2017' 
GROUP BY  MONTH(date)
```

but the result just get for 1 month.

```
{ ["a"]=> string(1) "1" ["b"]=> string(1) "6" }
```

how, if i want the result give result like this

```
{ 
      /*jan*/ ["a"]=> string(1) "0" ["b"]=> string(1) "0"
      /*feb*/ ["a"]=> string(1) "0" ["b"]=> string(1) "0"
      /*mar*/ ["a"]=> string(1) "0" ["b"]=> string(1) "0"
      /*apr*/ ["a"]=> string(1) "0" ["b"]=> string(1) "0"
      /*mei*/ ["a"]=> string(1) "0" ["b"]=> string(1) "0"
      /*jun*/ ["a"]=> string(1) "3" ["b"]=> string(1) "5"
      /*jul*/ ["a"]=> string(1) "4" ["b"]=> string(1) "8"
      /*aug*/ ["a"]=> string(1) "0" ["b"]=> string(1) "0"
      /*sep*/ ["a"]=> string(1) "0" ["b"]=> string(1) "0"
      /*okt*/ ["a"]=> string(1) "0" ["b"]=> string(1) "0"
      /*nov*/ ["a"]=> string(1) "0" ["b"]=> string(1) "0"
      /*des*/ ["a"]=> string(1) "0" ["b"]=> string(1) "0"
}
```

`/*month*/` just note the result is permonth. can this done by use `/*when case*/` query?

thanks

Comment: You should be getting two rows, not one, but in any case you might need to join with a calendar table to get the result you want.

Comment: You might want to return the month in your select statement: Output from the query is not ordered or guaranteed to be ordered. Similar once the data is parsed in json: Also not a guaranteed order in there (data order in is not guaranteed the data order when retrieved).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem would seem to be that you don't have data for all months.  You can use `left join` to get the data . . . here is a way:

```
SELECT  m.mon, SUM(tv.total_a) as a, SUM(tv.total_b) as b
FROM (SELECT 1 as mon UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL
      SELECT 5 as mon UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL
      SELECT 9 as mon UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12
     ) m LEFT JOIN
     table_visit tv
     ON MONTH(tv.date) = m.mon
WHERE YEAR(date) = 2017
GROUP BY m.mon;
```

Note that I included the month in the result set.  I just think that is a really good practice.

Also. `YEAR()` returns a number.  No need for single quotes around `2017`.